# Connecting to a SQL Compact file (.sdf) using an ADO connection in Delphi

Tags: delphi, sql-server-ce

I'm attempting to use a local .sdf file as a means of temporary storage should the main database be unreachable. I have the .sdf file, but when I try to set it to the file it seems to not at all know if the .sdf exists. The current connection string I have currently is:

```
 Driver={SQL Native Client};Data Source=C::\users\username\desktop\file\MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False
```

and for the Provider it generated for me:

```
 Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5
```

When I try to use the connection, I get a "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed." The .sdf is most definitely in the folder. I also had/have a problem with it wanting a username and/or password, neither of which I had to specify when creating the database.

The Question: Is there something wrong with my connection string? Is it reasonable to use ADO connections to access SQL Compact Databases? Might there be an easier way to query/retrieve data from a temporary storage (I would prefer doing it with SQL though)?
Most documentation seems to be from 2003/2005, which is unhelpful.

I used "connectionstrings.com" for help making the string. Any advice would be helpful, thanks

Comment: The error description is very clear, you must install the Oledb provider  before to use it, this is the download link of the provider http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5821

Comment: Checked it, "A later version is already installed". I do have a strong inclination that it is a problem with the Driver and/or Provider.

Comment: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each DB status value, if available. No work was done."

Comment: The issue must be related to your connection string, I made several apps using the oledb providers for SQL Server Compact without problems.

Comment: Do you have an example? I know not in the slightest if mine is even applicable. Broken down:
Driver={SQL Native Client}; Is it actually the driver if we keep changing the provider? I'm not sure, and I know not if im missing something vital to the string

Comment: With which version of Sql server compact was your sdf file created?

Comment: 3.5. I just uninstalled, reinstalled, and recreated the .sdf. Still claims the provider cannot be found/is not installed. I also made sure I was running the program as an administrator

Comment: The link you provided correlates to the service pack for Synchronization Services for ADO.NET version 1.0 Service Pack 1 for windows desktop, and was published on 8/6/2008, might that be a problem?

Comment: Check my answer, also you can test the connection to your sdf file using a third-party tool [SQL Compact 3rd party tools](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First to open the sdf file you must use a provider compatible with the version of the sdf file. since you mention in your comments the version 3.5 you must use this provider `Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5`

Then you must ensure which the provider is installed

Try this code to list the OLEDB providers installed in your system

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  Registry,
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

procedure ListOLEDBProviders;
var
  LRegistry: TRegistry;
  LIndex: Integer;
  SubKeys,Values: TStrings;
  CurKey, CurSubKey: string;
begin
  LRegistry := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    LRegistry.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
    if LRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly('CLSID') then
    begin
      SubKeys := TStringList.Create;
      try
        LRegistry.GetKeyNames(SubKeys);
        LRegistry.CloseKey;
        for LIndex := 0 to SubKeys.Count - 1 do
        begin
          CurKey := 'CLSID\' + SubKeys[LIndex];
          if LRegistry.KeyExists(CurKey)  then
          begin
            if LRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly(CurKey) then
            begin
              Values:=TStringList.Create;
              try
                LRegistry.GetValueNames(Values);
                LRegistry.CloseKey;
                for CurSubKey in Values do
                 if SameText(CurSubKey, 'OLEDB_SERVICES') then
                   if LRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly(CurKey+'\ProgID') then
                   begin
                     Writeln(LRegistry.ReadString(''));
                     LRegistry.CloseKey;
                     if LRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly(CurKey+'\OLE DB Provider') then
                     begin
                      Writeln('    '+LRegistry.ReadString(''));
                      LRegistry.CloseKey;
                     end;
                   end;
              finally
                Values.Free;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        SubKeys.Free;
      end;
      LRegistry.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    LRegistry.Free;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    ListOLEDBProviders;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Now this is a basic sample to connect to a Sql Server compact file.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  AdoDb,
  SysUtils;

procedure Test;
Var
  AdoQuery : TADOQuery;
begin
  AdoQuery:=TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    AdoQuery.ConnectionString:='Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=C:\Datos\Northwind.sdf';
    AdoQuery.SQL.Text:='Select * from Customers';
    AdoQuery.Open;
    While not AdoQuery.eof do
    begin
      Writeln(Format('%s %s',[AdoQuery.FieldByName('Customer ID').AsString,AdoQuery.FieldByName('Company Name').AsString]));
      AdoQuery.Next;
    end;
  finally
    AdoQuery.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Test;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: It was indeed installed, but for the provider it set for me the provider "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5", which is not a provider, "Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5" is. When I implimented a line similar to the
"AdoQuery.ConnectionString:='Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=C:\Datos\Northwind.sdf';"
it put the correct provider and did not yell at me that time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

also check **[this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa257373%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)** wich helps with protected databases

> "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.OLEDB.CE.2.0; data
>   source=\NorthWind.sdf; SSCE:Database Password="